# How to use record to loop a ref cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql, record, ref-cursor

I want to write PL/SQL to test a function in a package.  The package defines a cursor type

```
TYPE ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
```

I want to define a record based on that type.

My code is:

```
DECLARE
  cur PACKAGE_NAME.ref_cursor; 
  rec cur%ROWTYPE;
```

why is last line not correct?

Comment: Can you post the declaration of the cursor type in the package?  In particular, is the package declaring a strong or a weak cursor?

Comment: Hi Justin, this is declaration in the package that I want to test. (TYPE ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't define a record type based on a weakly-typed REF CURSOR.  Since the cursor type defined in the package can be used to return data from an arbitrary query with arbitrary columns, the PL/SQL compiler can't determine an appropriate record type to fetch the data into.

If you know the actual data being returned from the function, you could declare a record of that type to fetch the data into.  For example, if I declare a function that returns a weakly-typed cursor type but I know that the cursor really returns a cursor based on the `EMP` table, I can fetch the data into an `EMP%ROWTYPE` record (note that `SYS_REFCURSOR` is a system-defined weakly-typed REF CURSOR type)

```
create or replace function f1
  return sys_refcursor
is
  l_rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_rc
   for select *
         from emp;
  return l_rc;
end;

declare
  l_rc sys_refcursor;
  l_emp emp%rowtype;
begin
  l_rc := f1;
  loop
    fetch l_rc into l_emp;
    exit when l_rc%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line( l_emp.empno );
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: declare
  l_rc sys_refcursor;
  l_emp emp%rowtype;
begin what if i dont know type of l_emp or do not have permission on object type